texturing acting weird
I am fairly new to blender, did a few tutorials and alway struggling with texturing and the results when I do my own more complex structures.
Here a simple example: the left pane is a newly added pane mesh with a marble texture, the right one is a newly generated face started from 4 dots taken from another object which has the same texture / material.
I tried it this was as my texture looked distorted all the time like on the second picture.
I have no idea what could have gone wrong, any idea?
Sry if I haven't used the right terms - I am still in the beginning of that learning curve and happy to get feedback.



You are using UV coordinates for your texture. I highly doubt the newly created faces have usable UVs right out of the box when you did not unwrap them. I would highly recommend you watch beginner tutorials on UV unwrapping and UV mapping.

I didnt expect such a quick response, thanks.
Unwrapping did the trick - the faces (picture 02) had some UV map but I should have unwrapped it. Thank you :)
